# Is there any alternative other than Process to execute built-in shell commands in C#

Tags: c#, command-line, process

Is there any alternative other than Process to execute built-in shell commands in C#? Currently I am using Process class to run those commands. But in the current scenario I want to run more than 200 such commands in parallel. So spawning more than 200 processes is not a good idea. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Why do you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: As an aside, why would you need to run 200 commands in parallel? You do realise that multithreading them will likely be slower than sequential execution in many cases.

Comment: If you have to use "dos commands" then a seperate process is what you need and the `Process` class is the best way to manage that. However, I'm sure you could achieve your ultimate goal in a more elegant way. I can't say for sure without knowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Which built-in shell command do you want to execute? Maybe there's a .NET alternative to it...

Comment: Sounds to me as if you must be using the wrong tools for whatever it is you want to do. If you could provide a little more info on what you are trying to achieve, maybe we could provide some alternative advice?

Comment: There is an alternative, but wont stop from spawning multiple processes. `int pid = Interaction.Shell(@"cmd", AppWinStyle.NormalNoFocus, false, -1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Running a dos command" is the equivalent to "Creating a process and running it" so even if there is an other api, there will still be 200 processes (which, by the way, is nothing to worry about unless you're on a really, *really* tiny system)

Comment: You might want to reduce the number of spawned processes to a sane number anyway, though. You may need to run 200 commands in total, but likely not all of them at the same time. Batches of less than 10 at a time should suffice.

Comment: We are running an utility which will send some requests to a server. In order to load the server, we need to run the utilities in parallel. And when we start 200+ processes on a machine, its memory utilization goes high. And we do not have any permission to change the code in the utility to send more requests. So we are looking for an alternative. But it seems like there is not other way rather than changing the code in the utility itself.

Comment: @user1283104 You need to know what the utility actually does, then you can write the c# code to do it.

Comment: @Jodrell: Thats the point. Neither we are not supposed to change the code in the utility we are calling nor to simulate the working of the code using another utility. We have to use it and that is the reason am looking for alternatives. But it seems like I dont have much options . I will re-consult with my team regarding developing another utility with better options. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could but, shouldn't do

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

Interaction.Shell(...);
```

Note: You would have to add a reference to the the VisualBasic assembly.

This is a direct answer to your question but, not somthing you should do.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why "shouldn't do"

Comment: @user1283104 because, internally it is doing the same as Process.Start but encapsulates all the control and feedback away from the caller. It would be better to write a function to do the start, using the `Process` class directly. You wouldn't need to import the VisualBasic assembley and you would have more control over the usage.

Answer (score 0):

As Max Keller pointed out, `System.Diagnostics.Process` always starts a new system process.

If have to start processes/operations for more than just some seconds, I would prefer to save all commands in a temp file and execute this with `System.Diagnostics.Process` rather than ever single operation.

```
// Get a temp file
string tempFilepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "MyBatchFile.bat");
// Ensure the file dont exists yet
if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempFilepath)) {
    System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilepath);
}
// Create some operations
string[] batchOperations = new string[]{
    "START netstat -a",
    "START systeminfo"
};
// Write the temp file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(tempFilepath, batchOperations);

// Create process
Process myProcess = new Process();
try {
    // Full filepath to the temp file
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = tempFilepath;
    // Execute it
    myProcess.Start();
    // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself!
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Output any error to the console
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

// Remove the temp file
System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilepath);
```

Comment: Is that one of those asynchronous batch files?

Comment: @user1283104 Using the [START](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) windows will spawn a new process for each operation. I've edited my example.

Comment: @GodLesZ: Thanks for the help.. Now giving it a try.. :)